# PyImport_ImportModule("platform") returns NULL

Tags: python, python-3.7, cpython

I'm calling `PyImport_ImportModule` from a C# program. However, `PyImport_ImportModule("platform")` always returns NULL.

I have called:

```
Py_SetPythonHome("/usr/local/bin/python3.7");
Py_SetPath("/usr/local/lib/python3.7");
```

prior to calling `PyImport_ImportModule("platform")`.

`PyImport_ImportModule("sys")` seems to work though.

EDIT:

Upon further investigation, `PyErr_Fetch` gives me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError : No module named '_posixsubprocess'
```

Not sure what this means.

What could be wrong?

Comment: ok so in python `platform` is and object inside `sys` module. I never used `c-api` or other, but in the `c-api` i see function `PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject` which got param ` PyObject *fromlist` so I sugesst, You need to execute 2 calls. First `PyImport_ImportModule("sys")` and then the one which imports object from this module.

Comment: @Take_Care_: You're looking at the wrong thing. You're looking at the `sys.platform` string, but there's also a `platform` module.

Comment: @user2357112 ahh thanks, Yea because of the `sys` in description by default I just through about the `os.platform` :)